# HTML5 video detect keypress in full screen mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

While playing a video in full screen mode with the `<video>` tag in Chrome and Opera, keypress events are not being triggered.

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('space pressed')
    }
})
```

With the above code, pressing space while the video is playing normally, spits out 'space pressed' in the console, but nothing happens when I switch to full screen. The code works in FF, and I haven't yet tested in Safari.

Is there any way to detect the keypress event while in full screen mode?

Comment: Is this post useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163203/how-do-i-capture-keyboard-events-while-watching-an-html5-video-in-fullscreen-mod

Comment: Have a look here when implementing for Safari. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150601/substitute-for-allow-keyboard-input-javascript-full-screen/16676279#16676279

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that most browsers don't allow keyboard inputs while in fullscreen mode due to security reasons. Although in Chrome, i believe you can set the following for keyboard input to work:

`document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);`

I haven't tested this myself.

Also for more information check out the following:

[How do I capture keyboard events while watching an HTML5 video in fullscreen mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163203/how-do-i-capture-keyboard-events-while-watching-an-html5-video-in-fullscreen-mod)

[Using the fullscreen API in web browsers](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/)